# How to increase connection timeout using sqlalchemy with sqlite in python

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, operationalerror

I am using sqlite (v2.6.0) as database backend and using sqlalchemy(v0.7.9) to operate it.
Recently I got a error `OperationalError: (OperationalError) database is locked`

By searching stackoverflow a possible solution is to increase the timeout of a connection.
Referece: [OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked)

But I don't know how to did that in sqlalchemy (since connection are actually controlled by it)
Can someone give me a direction?

Comment: fwiw, increasing the timeout is likely only going to make this error less frequent.  it's better to implement retries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's `create_engine()` takes an argument `connect_args` which is a dictionary that will be passed to `connect()` of the underlying DBAPI (see [Custom DBAPI `connect()` arguments](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments)). [`sqlite3.connect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) accepts `timeout` argument, so this should work:

```
create_engine('sqlite:///some.db', connect_args={'timeout': 15})
```

Comment: In case anyone is trying to solve the same problem for PostgreSQL 9.3, the connect_args argument would be spelled differently: connect_args={'connect_timeout': 15}

Comment: The actual argument name depends on the dialect and driver that is used to connect to the database. The @SteveSaporta comments relates most probably to the `psycopg2` dbapi, while PostgreSQL has other possible drivers such as `pg8000` which expects a `timeout` argument.