# django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: django, sqlite

I moved a django project from eclipse (on windows) to a linux machine and tried to run it from the command line.

as soon as i did python manage.py runserver, I got : django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked

This is the first time I am running this project on linux (and sure enough, fuser on the cache.db file came up with nothing). I even tried clearning the contents of cache.db and running it, but I still get the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked

Comment: I did come across that question, but in my case, I have only 1 thread. So I dont think it is a concurrency issue

Answer (score -1):

In windows you can try to change the permission to the file or put the database file into a folder for setting the permission.

If the runerver command works, and after you run the error you can also increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option.

```
'OPTIONS': {
    # ...
    'timeout': 20,
    # ...
}
```