# "OperationalError: database is locked" when deploying site to Azure

Tags: python, django, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I have built a django website and a part of it is Microsoft authentication link.
When I upload the site to azure cloud and click on the "log in" link, I recieve the following error:

```
OperationalError at /login
database is locked
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://bhkshield.azurewebsites.net/login
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
database is locked
Exception Location: /home/site/wwwroot/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in _commit, line 240
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/usr/local/bin',
 '/home/site/wwwroot',
 '/home/site/wwwroot/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 14 Jun 2019 13:19:22 +0000
```

I am using sqlite3 (setting.py code piece):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error because I don't insert or commit anything to the database. 
My website consists only of one page that has a sign in link (4 views: home, contex intialize, login and callback). That's it. 

Just to mention, when I run the site locally, everything works. It stops working only after deployment. 
Another weird thing is that I have uploaded something like this before to another site on azure and the login worked. For some reason, it doesn't work now and I have no idea why...

Has anyone encountered this type of error and can help?

If you need me to provide more files' content, let me know which files and I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a duplication of this question: [OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked).

From the documentation of Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errorsoption

> SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can’t support a
>   high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors
>   indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than
>   sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one
>   thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and
>   another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.
>
> Python’s SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines
>   how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it
>   times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.
>
> If you’re getting this error, you can solve it by:
>
> Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite
>   becomes too “lite” for real-world applications, and these sorts of
>   concurrency errors indicate you’ve reached that point.
>
> Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database
>   transactions are short-lived.
>
> Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database
>   option

I have been developing a Django web app as well, and I chose a Azure SQL Server to be the database of the application. Everything has been working OK.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed it to Azure SQL and it worked. If anyone else does it as well, in settings.py remember to put `'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'` and not `'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'` like Microsoft says in the connection string.

Comment: @baby_bunny_x3 how wht did you do. I'm facing the same problem