# How to solve "Database is locked" in telethon related scripts

Tags: python, api, telethon

I try to run Basic commands from telethon in order to connect to Telegram and what I have is two errors:

> 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
>   **RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback  and DATABASE IS LOCKED**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import RpcMcgetFailError


api_id = xxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

phone_number = '+393333941671'
sesssion_name = 'scraper'

client = TelegramClient(sesssion_name,
                    api_id,
                    api_hash)

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start()
```

Error

```
__main__:9: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-21e0fd5ffefd>", line 11, in <module>
    client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start()

  File "C:\Users\Anca\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 236, in __init__
    DEFAULT_PORT

  File "C:\Users\Anca\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 157, in set_dc
    self._update_session_table()

  File "C:\Users\Anca\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 183, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')

OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: kill previous process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked)

Comment: Thank you. Which is the better way to check for the previous processes and kill them

Comment: Use task manager

Comment: you are running another client with same information in same time and its not impossible