# Python error 'sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked' when accessing database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

When I run a routine to open my database and insert values 
i get the error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

and a file is created with my database name (in the same directory)
system.db-journal.

Could anyone please help me? Before i run this routine i ran 
a login routine which accessed the database successfully with 
no errors. I have many other routines in the backend file what access the database and they finish with conn.commit and conn.close thus I don't know what the issue is - but feel it has something to do with the file generated.

A small subsection of the function which induces the error 
(Willing to provide more code but will get complicated quickly)

```
#frontend.py                                                        
backend.Database.customerOrders(choice,size,milkOptions,today,                                           
PageTwo.quantity,PageTwo.price,customerID)

#Backend.py
#INSERT ORDER DETAILS
def customerOrders(product,size,milkOptions,date,quantity,price,customerID):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO customerOrders VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(product,size,milkOptions,date,quantity,price,customerID))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

File created in same directory system.db-journal.

Comment: Do you have multiple open connections? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked

Comment: I have conn.close()  after every type of query, but I find it odd how a file is created about the database upon one of my queries, and this has something to do with the issue?

Comment: The issue could be if you are running multiple programs/processes that used backend.py. If you are running a server it is possible that it is using multiple processes, but I can't tell from the information given.