# unable to connect sqlite3 in python for long urls

Tags: python, better-sqlite3

I want to read a sqlite database in python.If i put the database in same working folder it opens.But if put long urls it dont work. File name is History and location is

**C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**

```py
con=sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\UserData\\Default\\History')
cur = con.cursor()
for row in cur.execute("SELECT id,title FROM 'urls' "):
    print(row)
con.close()
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with the space in "User Data" (which you don't have in your connect string)?

Comment: Thank you. can you help me for this problem
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: @songschannel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked#:~:text=OperationalError%3A%20database%20is%20locked%20errors,the%20lock%20the%20be%20released. This might help you.