# database_table locked during automated tests with Selenium Django

Tags: python, django, database, selenium

I use `django==3.1.2` and selenium and `selenium==3.141.0`.

I have a test file with 12 tests and when I execute them like so:

`python3 manage.py test myapp.tests --settings=app.settings_test` 2 of the tests fail. When I execute them singly like so

`python3 manage.py test myapp.tests.MyTests.test_this --settings=app.settings_test` they don't fail.

> The errors are usually something like
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: database table is locked:
> visitors_person
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> myapp_cars

...

> django.core.management.base.CommandError: Database
> file:memorydb_default?mode=memory&cache=shared couldn't be flushed.
> Possible reasons:   * The database isn't running or isn't configured
> correctly.   * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't
> exist.   * The SQL was invalid. Hint: Look at the output of
> 'django-admin sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to
> run.

or

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: database table is locked:
> myapp_drivers

It always errors on different models of the database.

My database in `settings_test.py` looks like this:

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME':   os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'db_test.sqlite3'),
    'OPTIONS': {
        'timeout': 20,
    }
}
```

During these tests I create about 120 entries spread over 12 tests, the fixtures install about 20 entries. So not that much. After googling the error I added the timeout and I added `time.sleep(1)` after each `MyModal.objects.create()` to see if this is the reason, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dup of [OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked)

Comment: not really, I already tried the solution from this post, such as adding a timer AND I think sqllite can handle 120 entries no?

Comment: Have you tried any other DBs other than SQLite, as mentioned in the post?

Comment: true, I have not, kk I'll remove it