# How to specify longer than default timout for sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am creating a small webapp with flask and sqlite, but in many cases I get the error that the database is locked.

in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked), there is a comment that one way to tackle this is by increasing the timeout however, I am not really sure on how to do that

there is this command that was suggested for Django, not sure how this would work for Flask `create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(xxx), connect_args={'timeout': 15})`

Comment: check the [sqlite3.connect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: You probably initialized connection somewhere in code, there's an option to set custom timeout.