SQLite database locking even with threading.Lock
I use sqlite3 database on my flask website, and on each database access I use a threading.Lock in order to avoid memory races:
# one sync, one connection, one cursor for the entirety of the website
sync = threading.Lock()
connection = sqlite3.connect('db', check_same_thread = false)
cursor = connection.cursor()
#...
with sync:
    cursor.execute(...) # just .execute(), i do not use .commit()

It works fine, when I use it on a localhost as a bare flask server. Even when I spam it with lots of requests, where each request has to access a database (and not once), it doesn't break. However, when I submit this code to a website hosting service, which uses Phusion Passenger, it generally works fine, but when I do too much requests, it results in sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked over and over again.
What do I do wrong? I used a mutex, why does the database get locked? Does it have something to do with the fact I use just one cursor?

I checked documentation related Phusion Passenger:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/processes.html
The problem is that all workers are running in different processes. It is not multi-thread, it is multi-processing.
In python is very frequent working with processes instead of threads due GIL (https://realpython.com/python-gil/)
I recommend you check following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172950/8054608
